# epmd error for host myhost: address (cannot connect to host/port) on windows 10

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl, epmd

I am trying to install rabbitmq. The installation of both erlang i.e OTP 18.1 file was done successfulyl and also rabbitmq installation completed successfully. But when I try to connect rabbitmq, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
Plugin configuration unchanged.
Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@INLN50899724A... failed.
 * Could not contact node rabbit@INLN50899724A.
   Changes will take effect at broker restart.
 * Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
            --offline - do not try to contact broker.
C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmq-server restart
ERROR: epmd error for host INLN50899724A: address (cannot connect to host/port)
```

Click below to see the image containing error
[Error Empd Rabbitmq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qyrz.png)

Answer (score 25):

Remove the RabbitMQ service. Uninstall RabbitMQ. Kill the epmd.exe process. Delete your c:\users\\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ Directory.

Go to Control Panels -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Add a variable named `RABBITMQ_NODENAME` and set it to `rabbit@localhost`

Reinstall RabbitMQ.

Navigate to the RabbitMQ sbin directory (or run the command from the start menu) and run `rabbitmqctl status`.

You should no longer see the **(cannot connect to host/port)** error.

And yes, this will fix your Cisco AnyConnect VPN related installation issues.

Comment: Worked for me. Nice!

Comment: Thanks, it is working in the version rabbitmq-server-3.7.15

Answer (score 24):

I may be replying really late, but still I'm facing this issue. So it may help somebody event while installing rabbitmq version 3.6.5. To change the node name, open "rabbitmq-env.bat" under "installation dir\sbin" and change RABBITMQ_NODENAME to "rabbit@localhost" (line number 90 in rabbitmq 3.6.5). But make sure you remove the windows service, do change the nodename, install service and start it. This worked for me.
  No other options worked for me which were marked as right answer in stackoverflow!

Comment: I had similar issue on my linux server named 176.vm
Rabbit tried to connect to host '176' that would not resolve

Comment: I'm even later to the party than you, but I wanted to point out that you can also set the value as a Windows environment variable as an alternative to editing the batch file

Answer (score 14):

open **C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.15\sbin\rabbitmq-server.bat**

Add the below command as the first line in

set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost

refer attached image

[image]

Comment: I had to do this in the service bat too

Comment: Thank you...After some time consuming troubleshooting, this worked so upvoting!

Answer (score 13):

For Windows Machine:

- Go in `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ`
- Create a file `rabbitmq-env.conf`
- Add the following:

  ```
  CONFIG_FILE=C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq
  NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
  NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
  ```
- The above is my env-config, for this particular issue setting
  the `nodename` will be sufficient.
- **Turn off you firewall & start the rabbitmq, it will work. After running it one time, even if you turn on the firewall, it will work.**

This works for me in Windows 10 machine.

Comment: I've changed `NODENAME=rabbit` to `NODENAME=rabbit@localhost` on my Linux machine, now it works for me as well, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

in your shell

```
$ export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
$ /sbin/rabbitmq-server  -detached
```

Answer (score 1):

change rabbit@INLN50899724A
to rabbit@localhost and try again.

Comment: Can you help me out with it .. How to do that? I have tried changing node name in conf file but it does not reflect.

Comment: find the location of config file in windows . For ex in linux it is found in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config . Try changing  the node name in the config file.

Comment: Yes, I have found rabbitmq.config file in C:\Users\<computerUser>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ.. but I saw that it is blank. So, Do you know what to write in it to change host name

Answer (score 0):

Or, edits your hosts file so that INLN50899724A points to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

For using rabbit mq on windows 10 for similar error I did below

1. set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
   in the path where rabbit MQ is installed i.e for me it was in C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.5\sbin>
   and then started
   .\rabbitmq-server start

Also, I had changed the host to point to my computer name in c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc
127.0.0.1   yourhostnamehere